# Merging data based on partial common fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Below is the query which I am using to generate the output as provided

```
SELECT A.MGR_EMP_NBR,E.FIRST_NM || ' ' || E.LAST_NM AS EMP_NM , A.AE_EMP_NBR,a.sales_terr_id, COUNT ( * ) AS pre_leads_total FROM MKVW_ECOMPORTAL_SCHEMA.ECOMWEB_LEADS A    
left join MKVW_MKV_SCHEMA.EMPLOYEE E on A.MGR_EMP_NBR = E.EMP_NBR    
WHERE A.SALES_TERR_ID like '1-2-7-56-%-%-%' AND A.MGR_EMP_NBR is NULL    
GROUP BY A.MGR_EMP_NBR, E.FIRST_NM || ' ' || E.LAST_NM , A.AE_EMP_NBR,a.sales_terr_id
```

Output-

```
MGR_EMP_NBR    EMP_NM   AE_EMP_NBR   sales_terr_id      pre_leads_total
                         1234        1-2-7-56-1-1-26    12
                         2311        1-2-7-56-1-1-27    11
                         414         1-2-7-56-1-5-26    10
```

I want to get the sum of values where the **sales_terr_id** has the first 6  number as common meaning combine `1-2-7-56-1-1-26 and 1-2-7-56-1-1-27`and giving the combined sales_terr_id as 1-2-7-56-1-1-0 .
So in this case I want to get the output as

Expected output-

```
  MGR_EMP_NBR    EMP_NM   AE_EMP_NBR   sales_terr_id      pre_leads_total
                             1234        1-2-7-56-1-1-0    23
                             414         1-2-7-56-1-5-0    10
```

Is it possible .I am not concerned with the AE_EMP_NBR.

Comment: sorry first 6 need to be checked ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by the first 6 numeric elements of the `sales_terr_id` you can group by a substring of that; as they are all numbers you could use a regular expression:

```
with t(MGR_EMP_NBR, EMP_NM, AE_EMP_NBR, sales_terr_id, pre_leads_total) as (
  select null, null, 1234, '1-2-7-56-1-1-26', 12 from dual
  union all select null, null, 2311, '1-2-7-56-1-1-27', 11 from dual
  union all select null, null, 414, '1-2-7-56-1-5-26', 10 from dual
)
select mgr_emp_nbr, emp_nm, min(ae_emp_nbr) as ae_emp_nbr,
  regexp_substr(sales_terr_id, '(\d+-){6}') ||'0' as sales_terr_id,
  sum(pre_leads_total) as pre_leads_total
from t
group by mgr_emp_nbr, emp_nm, regexp_substr(sales_terr_id, '(\d+-){6}');

MGR_EMP_NBR EMP_NM AE_EMP_NBR SALES_TERR_ID    PRE_LEADS_TOTAL
----------- ------ ---------- ---------------- ---------------
                          414 1-2-7-56-1-5-0                10
                         1234 1-2-7-56-1-1-0                23
```

You have to aggregate the `ae_emp_nbr` so I've used `min()` - you said you weren't concerned about that.

If you wanted to do that in your existing query in one go it would be something like:

```
select a.mgr_emp_nbr,
  e.first_nm || ' ' || e.last_nm as emp_nm,
  min(a.ae_emp_nbr) as ae_emp_nbr,
  regexp_substr(a.sales_terr_id, '(\d+-){6}') ||'0' as sales_terr_id,
  count (*) as pre_leads_total
from ecomweb_leads a    
left join employee e on a.mgr_emp_nbr = e.emp_nbr    
where a.sales_terr_id like '1-2-7-56-%-%-%'
and a.mgr_emp_nbr is null    
group by a.mgr_emp_nbr, e.first_nm || ' ' || e.last_nm,
  regexp_substr(a.sales_terr_id, '(\d+-){6}')
```